# How do I parse XML and feed the data into RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

My app currently pulls some API data from a site. I need it to show the elements in a RecyclerView list.

The API data is something like this:

```
<work>
    <id type="integer">54397325</id>
    <books_count type="integer">6</books_count>
    <ratings_count type="integer">21</ratings_count>
    <text_reviews_count type="integer">2</text_reviews_count>
    <original_publication_year type="integer" nil="true"/>
    <original_publication_month type="integer" nil="true"/>
    <original_publication_day type="integer" nil="true"/>
    <average_rating>4.10</average_rating>
    <best_book type="Book">
        <id type="integer">33584556</id>
        <title>
            Head First Android Development: A Brain-Friendly Guide
        </title>
        <author>
            <id type="integer">773952</id>
            <name>Dawn Griffiths</name>
        </author>
        <image_url>
            https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1492905802m/33584556.jpg
        </image_url>
        <small_image_url>
            https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1492905802s/33584556.jpg
        </small_image_url>
    </best_book>
</work>
```

I need the book title, author, and the image URL to list them in RecyclerView.

Comment: Are you using Retrofit to make an API call?

Comment: check this link to parse xml https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

Comment: @GiulioPettenuzzo In the link you provided, they used `InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.xml");`. How do I change this so that it reads the XML from the API request?

Comment: Did you read this? [Google Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml)

Comment: I post an answer to show you how to convert a string in InputStream assuming that youre xml is in string format

Answer (score 0):

follow this link to parse xml https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

remember that if in your application you have the xml text in string format you need to convert the xml string to an inputStream object like below

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleXMLString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```